# Font issue with Chrome on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fonts, cross-browser

I am working on a site where I am having a font issue.  The font shows up correctly for all browsers on a PC, but, the issue is when it is viewed with Chrome on a Mac.  I know how to do hacks for specific browsers, but, I am at a loss when it comes to Chrome on a Mac.  How do you specify for a particular browser on a Mac.  I've attached screen captures.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?  Thank you in advanced for your time and consideration.

[Correct Chrome on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1qu9.png)

[incorrect Chrome on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ6Xk.jpg)

Comment: where's your code that guarantees the correct font is used, irrespective of OS or browser? (e.g. where's your @font-face CSS?)

Comment: I researched the font-face CSS.  Is this what you are referring to:                    @font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src:  url('myfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('myfont.woff') format('woff');
}                                                                                                                         Will this help with keeping the size of the fonts consistent from browser to browser no matter which OS you're using?  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: it is, and please put that information in your question so that your question contains all the information. people shouldn't need the comments to get the whole story. If you use an @font-face rule, you are explicitly telling the browser which font to use, so as long as there are no 404s for the font url, or errors in the font itself, it'll then render the same typeface on all browsers and operating systems.

Comment: I appreciate the input.  This is the site:  http://pop.terrellplace.com/neighborhood.phpThe problem is the customer is looking at these things a mac.  On my pc, all browsers are showing it correctly.  This is the css where the problem is:  .hs-line-1 {
    font-size: 96px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    line-height: 1.0!important;                                                                              The font size just isn't correct.  I know how to use a browser hack that can fix individual browsers, but the issue seems to be that he is using a mac.  Can this fix it?

Comment: one piece of solid advice I have is to not use pixels, because they don't mean the same thing between devices with different pixel definitions, especially high-dpi devices, which is mostly Apple devices at the moment. Rather than pixels, try `rem` values, which are "em values relative to the document base value", which should work on all devices irrespective of pixel density and definition.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Ultimately I had to use javascript to resize the fonts in Safari on the Mac.  I appreciate the help and in the process I learned some much needed things.

Comment: That's... a really weird solution? Just reduce your use case to that single bit of plain HTML, see if using `rem` fixes it, if so, why on earth would you use JS to change styling when it's not necessary?

Comment: Thanks for the input, but rem was suggested and it didn't work.  It was a strange situation.  I had it working on all browsers on pc, especially Chrome.  But the issue was Chrome on the Mac.  Javascript ended up being the one solution that worked.